I am searching for my lost Solana tokens
It seems that my Phantom wallet was hacked during the transfer process, but on Solscan, I can see which wallet currently holds my SOL tokens. How can I file a complaint about this, or is there a way to recover my SOL tokens?
49SJyicGG4pyDY48pAZW22RovxZzK2rNC4TXt54frTn1vxZark3aoA6FXriZMwtnDAVeaBDrXBJeQdMvwu44GWjG"This is my transaction ID."
this is my signature"49SJyicGG4pyDY48pAZW22RovxZzK2rNC4TXt54frTn1vxZark3aoA6FXriZMwtnDAVeaBDrXBJeQdMvwu44GWjG"
Please, if anyone can provide assistance regarding this matter, let me know

Hi there, I'm sorry to hear you lost your funds. However, this site is dedicated to development on Solana and not for assistance regarding fund recovery. Maybe Phantom Support can help figure out what went wrong.

Hello, Phantom support is not providing any help, so I am looking for alternative solutions. When I say they are not helping, I mean I only receive AI responses that cannot resolve my issue. Perhaps you know the email address for Phantom support?
